# How to let objects fall down continually

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I have started learning Unity and want to let objects fall down and collect. So far I have just one object and it falls down just one time. How do i place in into a loop and let it fall over and over again?

```
public class AppleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float fallSpeed = 8.0f;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want it bounce back from floor or reappear from top?

Comment: I want it to reappear on top at another x position. I am using a for loop to create more apples in start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undestand it correctly, you want an object to fall down then teleport up to its starting position and then fall down again. Let's do that in code!

```
    public class AppleScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float fallSpeed = 8.0f;

        //Variables for starting position and length until reset
        private Vector3 _startingPos;
        public float FallDistance = 5f;

        void Start()
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.down * fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            // Save starting position
            _startingPos = transform.position;
        }

        void Update()
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.down * fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

            // If the object has fallen longer than 
            // Starting height + FallDistance from its start position
            if (transform.position.y > _startingPos.y + FallDistance) {
                transform.position = _startingPos;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had to change the last bit to < -5 and then the script for falling down and start over at the top worked.Thanks for your help.  It also has to start at a random x point at the top.